# Get description for event in current popup

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, tampermonkey

I'm currently trying to write my own tampermonkey script to insert an event's description into the popup within Google Calendar. *(EDIT: The popup showing the details of a specific event when clicking on it)*

Unfortunately Google calendars internal JS libraries hide the actual request / link (so I don't know what POST / GET request is actually executed or how it is generated - it's just "javascript:void(0)").

So there are three different solutions I came up with (a question for every single one):

- Is it possible to find out the event ID of the currently displayed popup in Google Calendar with tampermonkey? (afterwards I can use the official JavaScript API)
- Is it possible to clone a complete website context within tampermonkey? This would allow me executing the click (in a different context, so without changing the current page), parse the description and reuse it in the current context.
- Is it possible (in a reasonable amount of time) to find out what exactly is executed after the "javascript:void(0)" click to reverse engineer the request creation (this also means that I have to have access to the javascript's context f.e. for the current event ID).

Thanks for any answers / help!

**Edit:**
I do already have access to the window's JS context (with @grant unsafeWindow) but if I can find the event's ID somewhere in the context (couldn't find it until now) I would still have to manually call the Google Calendar API. I was wondering if there is an easier way to find the description of the currently displayed event (in the current event popup).

My current code looks like this (The section where I want to read the description is marked with the TODO):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         EnhanceGCal
// @version      0.1
// @description  Script to enhance the Google Calendar popup view
// @license      Apache License 2.0
// @match        https://www.google.com/calendar/*
// @grant        unsafeWindow
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// @require      https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth
// ==/UserScript==

console.log('Started....')

// check if the bubble is available
if (!$('.bubblecontent').length) { console.log('Nothing found...'); return; }

// Try enhance the popup everytime it is created
$('.bubblecontent').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    var table, tbody, tr, td1, td2;
    table = document.getElementsByClassName('eb-data')[0];
    if (!table) { return; }
    tbody = table.childNodes[0];
    if (!tbody) { return; }

    if (window.currentlyEditing) { return; }
    window.currentlyEditing = true;

    // add a new table row for the description
    if (!$('#enhanceGCalDescriptionRow').length) {
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.id = 'enhanceGCalDescriptionRow';
        td1 = document.createElement('td');
        td1.innerHTML="<b>Description</b>";
        td2 = document.createElement('td');
        td2.innerHTML="Description text";
        td2.id = 'enhanceGCalDescriptionText';
        tr.appendChild(td1);

        tr.appendChild(td2);
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }

    // TODO read the description of the current event and set it in the new table column
    $('#enhanceGCalDescriptionText').text('Enter description of the event in the popup here...');

    window.currentlyEditing = false;
});
```

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is unclear and too broad for succinct answers. Clarify: "popup within Google Calendar"; there are many. Clarify: "_the_ JS libraries". Describe what you've done, so answerers don't waste time rehashing the same ground. For example, have you used browser tools to examine the page and looked for the event ID? What did you find?

Comment: You can set an XHR breakpoint in the devtools debugger: F12 -> Sources -> XHR Breakpoints (right sidebar) -> [x] Any XHR. Or you can view the requests on the Network tab and then click in the initiator column to open the script source. Then use `{}` button on the left bottom to beautify the minified code.